# combining data from multiple lines into a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some code which pulls from multiple tables of a MS SQL database, arranges the data and outputs an array, I then need to use that array to populate a worksheet telling someone what items are needed on a day to day basis. Right now the output looks like the below, where the fields are ID, Name, Date, number (they are asterisk deliminated because some names include commas).

```
74*xxxx*2017-06-04*1
74*xxxx*2017-06-05*1
74*xxxx*2017-06-06*2
74*xxxx*2017-06-07*2
74*xxxx*2017-06-08*2
74*xxxx*2017-06-09*2
74*xxxx*2017-06-10*2
75*yyyy*2017-06-05*123
75*yyyy*2017-06-06*111
75*yyyy*2017-06-07*124
75*yyyy*2017-06-08*107
75*yyyy*2017-06-09*194
75*yyyy*2017-06-10*195
```

I am trying to get them to merge them into a single value per ID so that I can print it out to a grid to look similar to:

```
| ID | NAME | 06-04 | 06-05 | 06-06 | 06-07 | 06-08 | 06-09 | 06-10 |
| 74 | xxxx |   1   |   1   |   2   |   2   |   2   |   2   |   2   |
| 75 | yyyy |   -   |  123  |  111  |  124  |  107  |  194  |  195  |
```

my intent was to merge the array values into a single array with the dates as the keys, the (most recent) code I was trying is:

```
$schedule[] = $PID . "*" . $program . "*" .  $date . "*" .  $num;


$grid = array();
foreach ($schedule as $item ) {

    $ex = explode('*', $item);
    $grid[$ex[0]] = array(
        'name' => $ex[1],
        $ex[2] => $ex[3],
    );
}
```

with the intent that that would merge them into a single array line to look like:

```
[74] => Array ( [name] => xxxx [2017-06-04] => 1 [2017-06-05] => 1 [2017-06-06] => 2 [2017-06-07] => 2 [2017-06-08] => 2 [2017-06-09] => 2 [2017-06-10] => 2)
```

after which I could just use it line by line with $grid[$i][1] etc to pull the value and print to each cell. I've tried other methods than the above, that is the only one I presently have the code snippet for and I've only been able to get it to keep the last value I add on a per ID basis.

I'm certain there is a piece I am missing or simply not understanding, if anyone could offer some input it would be appreciated.

Comment: If no one responds I'll try to put together an example that uses http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, the below code will give the desired array.

```
$schedule[] = '74*xxxx*2017-06-04*1';
$schedule[] = '74*xxxx*2017-06-05*1';
$schedule[] = '74*xxxx*2017-06-06*2';
$schedule[] = '74*xxxx*2017-06-07*2';
$schedule[] = '74*xxxx*2017-06-08*2';
$schedule[] = '74*xxxx*2017-06-09*2';
$schedule[] = '74*xxxx*2017-06-10*2';
$schedule[] = '75*yyyy*2017-06-05*123';
$schedule[] = '75*yyyy*2017-06-06*111';
$schedule[] = '75*yyyy*2017-06-07*124';
$schedule[] = '75*yyyy*2017-06-08*107';
$schedule[] = '75*yyyy*2017-06-09*194';
$schedule[] = '75*yyyy*2017-06-10*195';

$grid = array();
foreach ($schedule as $item ) {
    $ex = explode('*', $item);
    $grid[$ex[0]]['name'] = $ex[1];
    $grid[$ex[0]][$ex[2]] = $ex[3];
}
print_r($grid);
```

And out put is

```
Array
(
    [74] => Array
        (
            [name] => xxxx
            [2017-06-04] => 1
            [2017-06-05] => 1
            [2017-06-06] => 2
            [2017-06-07] => 2
            [2017-06-08] => 2
            [2017-06-09] => 2
            [2017-06-10] => 2
        )

    [75] => Array
        (
            [name] => yyyy
            [2017-06-05] => 123
            [2017-06-06] => 111
            [2017-06-07] => 124
            [2017-06-08] => 107
            [2017-06-09] => 194
            [2017-06-10] => 195
        )

)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I'm glad to see I was closer than I expected to the right track too.

Thank you!